# smarty help with if statement

Tags: exception, compiler-construction, if-statement, smarty

I tried this code:

```
{if $login_status eq '1' }
    <a href="{$html_header.base_url}login.php?logout " >Logout </a>
{/if}
```

and passed the value {$login_status=1}.

This causes:

```
Uncaught exception 'SmartyCompilerException' with message 
'Syntax Error in template "tmpl\admin_login.tpl"  on line 2 "{if $login_status eq '1' }"  - Unexpected " }"' in C:\wamp
```

Which is not working. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of the space before the ending bracket.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a difference, but have you tried any of these below? What you have included looks correct.

```
{if $login_status == '1'}
{if $login_status == 1}
{if ($login_status == '1')}
```

I'm assuming that `{html_header.base_url}` is a custom function of yours. I would just want to eliminate the question if it's causing any problems by replacing it with something static until you solve the `{if}` issue.

Comment: some how it fix himself, with none changes from my side. tanks .